# Access webpage's localStorage from a Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

i'm developing a **chrome extension** which requires to get the values(to plugin) *from local storage* where values are stored by some other webpages that were created by me

In short: Access a webpage's localStorage from a Chrome extension script

Answer (score 15):

I just tested it, and if you access `localStorage` from the context of a content script, you get the webpage's localStorage. So, nothing special is required besides injecting a content script into the webpage you need.

To communicate the value from the content script you can use [Messaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging), and you can use [`chrome.storage.local` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) to save data in a way that's accessible from both the content script and the background page.

Comment: Wow, this means that any chrome extension have access to my localstorage on any website.

Comment: @George Absolutely not. You require a content script running in the context of a page to access this, and for that you need either of two things: a host permission for that domain (which gives you a lot more than just localStorage access!) or something like activeTab permission, which grants access if you explicitly do something with the extension (e.g. click it's icon in the toolbar). Extensions show appropriate access warnings on install and these days you can actually restrict access further on a case by case basis as well.

Comment: alright, thanks for the additional information