# localStorage removeitem not working on Chrome/Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, local-storage, browser-extension

I'll try to delete a localStorage Item in JS with my Chrome/Firefox extension, but it seems like it won't work, and now I would like to know how can I debug this problem, here my code from my popup.js:

```
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
btn.innerText = "Delete matchs";
btn.onclick = function () {
    localStorage.removeItem('save_to_storage');
};
```

my popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <script src='popup.js' defer></script>
  </head>
    <body>
      <div id='button'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

my manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "TEST",
    "version": "2021.07.31",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Test",
    "author": "lucki1000",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "favicon.ico",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "content_script":[
        {
            "js": ["popup.js"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>", "storage", "activeTab"]
}
```

If I press the button `Delete matchs` the `save_to_storage` item still appears in my developer tools, but if i type directly into the console `localStorage.removeItem('save_to_storage');` it works as expected.
I test it in firefox and chromium.

I also tried to get the value of this item by using `alert(localStorage.getItem('save_to_storage'));` instead of `localStorage.removeItem('save_to_storage');` in my popup.js but this alert was empty.

Can it be that my popup.js can't access this item? and if yes how can I solve this?

Test Enviroment:

```
Chromium Version 92.0.4515.107 (Offical Build) Arch Linux (64-Bit)
Mozilla Firefox 90.0.2 (64-Bit) for Arch Linux
```

Regards

Lucki1000

Comment: Is that a content script? It should execute in the context of the web page, so it should be able to access its `localStorage`.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23082216/1491895) claims that you shouldn't have to do anything special to access local storage from a content script.